# Background images not showing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image

I have a firefox-specific issue with this page :

http://www.buzzx.com/feedback.php

It renders fine in IE, Safari, Chrome and every other browser invented by man, but in Firefox the background images do not show (The 'Feedback' link on the left and a white box around the content).

Any help appreciated, I'm completely stumped here.

update : the images show if i put in the full path in the css - http://www.buzzx/..../images/... as opposed to having a relative path. but i really want to avoid doing this.

Comment: Weird. It shows up in FF when you manually load the PNG file, and reload the page, but only for a second. Interested to see what the cause is

Comment: actually, on a mac, I get the exact same result on Firefox v3.6.10, Chrome 6.0.472.62, and Opera 10.62

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem today, I can't see your css, but, this is what I found out, I had to move the html portion to the bottom of the css, at least below the other background elements I had, so that it would show. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just getting into Webdesign HTML & CSS, I had the same problem.

I used Webdwarf webdesigner to build the basic layout for the website. At first it didn't show in Firefox, but then I also put up an over-sized transparent picture made in GIMP. Just a big square with 100% transparancy. I checked it by clearing the cache in advanced options in Firefox and reloading the page. Changed the background picture a few times, hit reload button and it changed straightaway.

Other problem is often the path string. Webdwarf made the CSS coding for the background for me and  used the path string from the current location. *background-image:url (./images/background.jpg)*. It seems firefox wont accept a full length string for the background image

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [check against a validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buzzarab.com%2Ffeedback.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), just to make sure.

```
Line 48, Column 48: document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag 
    <h1><div class="page_heading"><div class="fleft">Contact Us</div><div
```

Comment: thanks, all the validation erros are minor and not related to the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird!

But I noticed one thing: the images don't load when there's a javascript error (I see it with Firebug) related to Google Ads. The message says:

Permission denied to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net to call the Location.toString method on http://www.buzzarab.com.

Line 0

Try and test the page without Google ads.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, removing google ads didn't fix it.

Comment: You're right, I downloaded your page and the problem remains, even if I strip away all scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding full path to the css, not a real fix but will do for now till a proper fix is found.